Template to drag/drop an image to overlay a shader?
How to Automate Mixing Image Alpha with a Shader?
In this case, using materialiq (a procedural shader) and mixing an image over it. With multiple shaders, this process is tedious. How can I automate it or build a template to drag and drop an image to overlay a shader? Or at least have the five necessary nodes already set up?


You could create a custom node group by selecting everything you want in there, press Ctrl+G (press Tab to get out of the group like switching from Edit Mode working in the viewport). Connect everything you want to control from outside of the group to the Group Input, and every result you want to output to the Group Output. By the way, the Alpha output of an image is a float value, the Color Ramp_ when only using black and white gives a float value, and the Fac input of the Mix Shader node needs a float value. You can multiply with a Math node, no Vector Math required.

do you know decal add-on? maybe that's a help for you?

@GordonBrinkmann: stop writing answers in comments - upvote anyway ;) i still cannot believe you format your comments - i still don't format my answers :D

@Chris I usually want to put screenshots in my answers to illustrate what I'm writing, but I was on my phone not on a PC, so no way to write a proper answer (to my taste)...  and I was not sure which nodes should be included.
